# marquee show 5 pics max when i pass 10 pics

Tags: asp.net, html

i use marquee to show pics but when i pass 10 pics it show 5 pics only 
here's My Code :

```
<marquee align="right" behaviour="alternate" scrollamount="4" direction="left" onmouseover="this.scrollAmount=0"
                            onmouseout="this.scrollAmount=4">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample01.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample02.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample03.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample04.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample05.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample06.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample07.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample08.jpg" /> </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="Slide_Images/sample09.jpg" /> </a>
</marquee>
```

Comment: why do you have to use marquee? it's definitely things in the past.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be because it's styled as an `alternate`. It can only bounce when there's room enough to do so (and, from what you're explaining, 5 images takes up that much real-estate). Maybe switch to a scroll?

(I also don't know how big the images are, so if you can provide that information I can update my answer.)